# How to make Transparent markers on Unfolding Maps?

Tags: maps, processing, opacity, transparent, marker

I am displaying multiple markers on Google Maps using Processing with unfolding maps library.
I would like to know whether there is any way to set the transparency to markers? Any opacity level I can specify?

Thanks in advance,
Hasala

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using one of the default markers? If so, which ones?

In general, you should be able to set the stroke and fill colors of the markers where you can also specify transparency in the normal Processing way.

```
myMarker.setColor(color(255, 0, 0, 100));
```

Check out the [SimpleMarkerManagerApp](https://github.com/tillnagel/unfolding/blob/master/examples/de/fhpotsdam/unfolding/examples/marker/SimpleMarkerManagerApp.java) example.

Comment: Hi, I use default markers. I tried changing the 4th parameter of the given method and then appears transparent. Thank you very much for the support.

Comment: Please close your question by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer that helped you most.